# IndexError: index x is out of bounds for axis 0 with size x

Tags: python, matplotlib, numerical-methods, numerical-integration, index-error

I am going to plot the velocity function of time, when I have gathered acceleration function of time.
However, I get an error code, `IndexError: index 51 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 51`, 51 is the last index of my data, as my data is set up like this: `f.write(str(akselerasjon) + "   "+ str(tid) + "\n")`, gathered it in MicroPython. However, the error takes place in python where I am dealing with the data.

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat May 22 21:04:05 2021

@author: Petter Jansen Ytterdahl
"""

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def rektangelmetoden(aks, tid):
    a_v = len(tid)
    vm = [0]
    t_v = 0
    
    for i in range(a_v - 1):
        h = tid[i + 1] - tid[i]
        t_v += aks[i] * h
        vm.append(t_v)
    return(vm)    

f = np.loadtxt("målinger.txt", float, skiprows = 0)
acceleration = f[:, 0]
time = f[:, 1]

gravitational_acceleration = 9.81 
mass = 0.5
k = 0.01 

m_v = []
m_t = []
t_start = 0
t_end = 5
steps = 1000
length_steps = (t_end-t_start)/(steps-1) 
 
velocity = np.zeros(steps) 
time = np.zeros(steps) 

for i in range(steps-1):
    velocity[i+1] = velocity[i] + length_steps * (gravitational_acceleration - k * velocity[i]**2 / mass)
    time[i+1] = time[i] + length_steps 

velocity_r = rektangelmetoden(acceleration, time)

plt.plot(time, velocity, color = "b", label = "Teoretisk modell")
plt.plot(time, velocity_r, color = "r", label = "målinger")
plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
plt.ylabel("Velocity [m/s]")
plt.title("Micro:Bit in parachute")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
```

The error takes place in this line (line 18):

```
t_v += aks[i] * h
```

I did see a few other similar errors on Stackoverflow, but I am too stupid to understand most of them, so please help, Thanks.

Comment: Why don’t you try debugging such as printing `i` And `len(aks)` before the line where the error happens, so you can check that `i` is always `<= len(aks)`

Comment: You are dealing with derivatives so you lose a point every time. You might want to add an initial 0 acceleration value to your list: `aks.insert(0, 0)`. Alternatively, `rektangelmetoden` probably gives results close to `scipy.integrate.trapezoid`.

Comment: idk what i did, but it worked, so thanks for the help/effort guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat May 22 21:04:05 2021

@author: Petter Jansen Ytterdahl
"""

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def rektangelmetoden(aks, tid):
    a_v = len(tid)
    vm = [0]
    t_v = 0

    for i in range(a_v - 1):
        try:
            h = tid[i + 1] - tid[i]
            t_v += aks[i] * h
            vm.append(t_v)
        except IndexError:
            break
    return(vm)


f = np.loadtxt("målinger.txt", float, skiprows=0)
acceleration = f[:, 0]
time = f[:, 1]

gravitational_acceleration = 9.81
mass = 0.5
k = 0.01

m_v = []
m_t = []
t_start = 0
t_end = 5
steps = 1000
length_steps = (t_end-t_start)/(steps-1)

velocity = np.zeros(steps)
time = np.zeros(steps)

for i in range(steps-1):
    velocity[i+1] = velocity[i] + length_steps * \
        (gravitational_acceleration - k * velocity[i]**2 / mass)
    time[i+1] = time[i] + length_steps

velocity_r = rektangelmetoden(acceleration, time)

plt.plot(time, velocity, color="b", label="Teoretisk modell")
plt.plot(time, velocity_r, color="r", label="målinger")
plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
plt.ylabel("Velocity [m/s]")
plt.title("Micro:Bit in parachute")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
```

I simply add a try/except block to catch the index error and break out of the `for loop`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you use derivatives, so your acceleration data has one fewer point than your velocity data. You could add a 0 value at the start (0-index) of the acceleration array like so `aks.insert(0, 0)` before iterating over it.

Now, there are many things in the code you do manually that can be essentially one-liners in numpy. Here are my suggestions:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz

# Calculate experimental velocity.
f = np.loadtxt("målinger.txt", float, skiprows=0)
acceleration_r = f[:, 0]
time_r = f[:, 1]
velocity_r = cumtrapz(acceleration_r, time_r, initial=0)

# Time array.
# I thought you'd like measured and theoretical times to automatically start and end at the same spots. 
t_start = time_r[0]
t_end = time_r[-1]
STEPS = 1000
time = np.linspace(t_start, t_end, STEPS, endpoint=True)
dt = time[1] - time[0]

# Calculate theoretical velocity.
g = 9.81
m = 0.5
k = 0.01
velocity = np.zeros(steps)
for i in range(steps-1):
    velocity[i+1] = velocity[i] + dt*(g - k*velocity[i]**2/m)

# Plot and compare both velocities.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.show()
ax.plot(time, velocity, color = "b", label = "Teoretisk modell")
ax.plot(time_r, velocity_r, color = "r", label = "målinger")
ax.set_xlabel("Time [s]")
ax.set_ylabel("Velocity [m/s]")
ax.set_title("Micro:Bit in parachute")
ax.grid()
ax.legend()
```

Note that I am using `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz` instead of your own function (`rektangelmetoden`) but both face the issue of losing one point. Scipy fixes this with the `initial=0` keyword which adds an initial value to the velocity and restores it to the same length as the acceleration and  time arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you used `time` twice, once reading from the file and once constructing it for the reference solution, with an unrelated length. However, after the second you tried to use that array again in the context of the first, with disastrous results, as to be expected.

Give the time arrays different names, `time_file` and `time_ref` or what you imagine.